# iOS14 WKWebView crash when long press on image, createGraphicsContext()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, wkwebview

My app is using WKWebView to show some html content. But on iOS 14.4.2, it crashes when I long press on an image when it about to trigger the preview popup. And it's wired that:

1. For now I can only reproduce it on one specific image with size of 16.5MB
2. Test with other image, it would not run into the crash.

[The crash stack trace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og5iL.jpg)

[video of how it crash](https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/538203614)

Please see the stack trace below, our app doesn't handle the long press gesture. And the stack trace is all about UIKit & WebKit. I assume this would be a iOS bug.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts or you ran into the similar issue too.